# fail to load iWork file url in documentPicker:didPickDocumentAtURL:

Tags: ios, objective-c, icloud

I'm working on an iOS app which can import cloud files using DocumnetPicker, Under Xcode6.1, iphone5s(IOS8.1.1). It's strange that url of .number/.key file could not be load successfully, but others like .pdf/.jpg are fine.

My UTIS:

```
+ (NSArray*) supportedDocumentTypes
{
    return @[(__bridge NSString*) kUTTypeContent,
             @"com.apple.iwork.pages.pages",
             @"com.apple.iwork.numbers.numbers",
             @"com.apple.iwork.keynote.key"];
}
```

documentPicker:didPickDocumentAtURL: is defined the same in newbox sample:

```
- (void)documentPicker:(UIDocumentPickerViewController *)controller didPickDocumentAtURL:(NSURL *)url {
    BOOL startAccessingWorked = [url startAccessingSecurityScopedResource];
    NSURL *ubiquityURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];
    NSLog(@"ubiquityURL %@",ubiquityURL);
    NSLog(@"start %d",startAccessingWorked);

    NSFileCoordinator *fileCoordinator = [[NSFileCoordinator alloc] init];
    NSError *error;
    [fileCoordinator coordinateReadingItemAtURL:url options:0 error:&error byAccessor:^(NSURL *newURL) {
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:newURL];
        NSLog(@"error %@",error);
        NSLog(@"data %@",data);
    }];
    [url stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe those are directories (containers) technically, which is why .pdf works but not the .numbers, etc.